# Running tests .mjs / ESM on Node using Jasmine or any other alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jasmine, es6-modules

My Node-based project is implemented using native ES module support on Node thanks to the `--experimental-modules` CLI switch (i.e. `node --experimental-modules`).

Obviously, when I run a spec using Jasmine `node --experimental-modules ./node_modules/jasmine/bin/jasmine`  I get the following error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module

Is it ever possible to use Jasmine using ES modules in Node?

If not, is there any alternative to *don't use a framework* (e.g. running tests with `npm` scripts)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was easier than I thought.

It's just about calling a file which you might call `run.mjs` as follows:

`node --experimental-modules ./run.mjs`

The whole file would look like this:

`jasmine.mjs`:

```
import Jasmine from "jasmine"
import JasmineConsoleReporter from "jasmine-console-reporter"

const jasmine = new Jasmine()
jasmine.loadConfigFile( "./support/jasmine.json" )

jasmine.env.clearReporters()
jasmine.addReporter( new JasmineConsoleReporter( {
    colors: true,
    cleanStack: true,
    verbosity: 4,
    listStyle: 'indent',
    activity: false
} ) )

export default jasmine
```

And you would add specs as follows in separate files:

```
import jasmine from './my-project/spec/jasmine.mjs'

jasmine.env.describe('Foo', () => {
    jasmine.env.it('Bar', () => {
        // Expects, assertions...
    })
})
```

Finally, you would run `jasmine` importing both configured `jasmine` instance and specs:

```
import jasmine from './my-project/spec/jasmine.mjs'
import someSpec1 from './my-project/spec/someSpec1.mjs'
import someSpecN from './my-project/spec/someSpecN.mjs'

someSpec1()
someSpecN()

jasmine.execute()
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was hoping to avoid changing the tests themselves, so until it's supported properly I've gone with using rollup and sourcemaps instead of Jasmine alone. Not ideal but at least means my tests stay clean. Good to know it's possible if I need to change it!

Comment: @Dave You can stay them clean exporting `describe` and other functions binding them to `jasmine`:  `export const describe = jasmine.env.describe.bind(this)`

Comment: @Dave Changing the module load system isn't the hard part. The problem is that ejs modules load async. So the entire flow starting at `jasmine.execute()` needs to be refactored as async code. This is reasonable, but will probably take some time. This is why your modification silently failed and why the workaround eventually requires invoking the specs individually rather then through the jasmine config. A nicer workaround could be parsing the config before jasmine.execute(), handling the *.mjs files, and leaving the *.js files for the regular load.

Comment: FYI, I didn't need to import jasmine in the spec file. All the globals are still there and point to the correct env. (addMatchers in helper file works, for example)

Comment: https://github.com/Tetnacious/jasmine-npm/tree/node-experimental-modules-support
Temporary fix, automaticlly handles mjs specs and helpers. Just reference instead of jasmine-npm. Execute returns a Promise.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying the solution of @Matias_Fidemraizer, keeping only the important bits in one file:

```
import glob from 'glob';
import Jasmine from 'jasmine';

const jasmine = new Jasmine();
jasmine.loadConfigFile('tests/jasmine.json');

// Load your mjs specs
glob('**/*-test.mjs', function (er, files) {
    Promise.all(
        files
            // Use relative paths
            .map(f => f.replace('tests/specs/', './'))
            .map(f => import(f)
                .catch(e => {
                    console.error('** Error loading ' + f + ': ');
                    console.error(e);
                    process.exit(1);
                }))
    )
        .then(() => jasmine.execute());
});
```

And execute it with

```
node --experimental-modules jasmine-run.mjs
```

You will have some problems in the logs, receiving a message like

> [...]   .split('\n') [...]

That message mean that you have an exception in the mjs code.

You can follow there: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/issues/150