# JavaScript test runner that supports native modules

Tags: javascript, testing, module

Is there a JavaScript test runner that supports native modules?

Answer (score 1):

*UPDATE for 2022: Jest now supports native modules experimentally.  Complete information on configuring it, and information about current issues, can be found [in the Jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules).*

Facebook's [Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest) supports native modules fairly painlessly through the use of the `babel-jest` [plugin](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/packages/babel-jest).

I'm not aware of any runners that don't require transpilation.  Would love to know about them if they exist.

There is another answer here that discusses using Node's experimental module support to test with Jasmine, but I'm not sure this is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47835049/3084820

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/index.html), 
[Jest](https://jestjs.io/) or [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/). 
Onestly, I prefer Karma or Jest